# Where to find vmlinux file for Debian?

Tags: debian, kernel

I have installed Debian 5.0.7 with kernel version 2.6.26-2-amd64.
I don't find the linux-image-dbg package inside install dvd. I need the vmlinux image of installed kernel for running crash utility.

Where do I get the vmlinux for this kernel?

Thanks,
Anandan

Comment: What crash utility are you going to run exactly?

Comment: standard crash utility. I got this from (http://packages.debian.org/lenny/crash)

Answer (score 1):

It's usually in the root (the topmost folder in your unix filesystem is called the root), and the main linux kernel file is usually symbolically linked using the name `/vmlinuz`  The z replaces the x and indicates it's compressed.

Update : I thought I might be able to extract the compressed image somehow, like this, but this doesn't work:

```
gunzip /vmlinuz > /tmp/vmlinux
```

Comment: localhost:/# file /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-custom-kdump
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-custom-kdump: Linux kernel x86 boot executable RO-rootFS, root_dev 0x801, swap_dev 0x1, Normal VGA

Comment: How do i get the vmlinux from this vmlinuz?
I want to this run crash utility.

Comment: You could try using the crash utility with this kernel image, and it will probably just work, because most unix utilities will automatically recognize and decompress the compressed kernel image.

Comment: I tried running the crash utility on this and i got this error.
_crash: vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-amd64: not a supported file format_
Also, gunzip does not work. It fails with error _"not in gzip format"_